# pass a javascript variable within a html page into a html form (on the same page) for submission to perl cgi

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var id = getValue("ID");
document.write(id);
</script>    

<form action="cgi-bin/runalg.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="radio" name="genome" value="E.Coli"> <i>E.Coli</i> <input type="radio" name="genome" value="Human"> Human<br> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"/>
</form>

</body>
```

How do I get the value of the JavaScript variable (var id) into the form so that on submission I can retrieve it in the `runalg.cgi` using the `$q<-param("ID")` command?

Comment: ;
    </script>

    <form action="cgi-bin/runalg.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="radio" name="genome" value="E.Coli"> <i>E.Coli</i> <input type="radio" name="genome" value="Human"> Human<br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear"/>
    </form>

    </body>

HOW DO I GET THE VALUE OF THE JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE (var id) INTO THE FORM SO THAT ON SUBMISSION I CAN RETRIEVE IT IN THE runalg.cgi USING THE $q<-param("ID") command?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit this into your question and please don't use capslock. It feels as if you shout at the reader...

Comment: Sorry for that, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can write it directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'+id+'"/>');
</script>
```

Comment: That input is not within the form.

Comment: yeah, how did you find this out? he didn't tell us where is the <script> section

Comment: [document.getElementById("input_id").value = id](https://jsfiddle.net/qqqr87d7/1/) will also work

Answer (score 2):

Add a hidden field. Set the value in that field to the value of the variable in Javascript.

```
<form action="cgi-bin/runalg.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
[...]
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="default">
</form>
```

And then on javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms[0].elements["ID"].value = getValue("ID");
</script>
```

The index for the form may vary in your document.

Comment: if you need "a few minutes to add the code." - change you job

Comment: you are welcome, also I have to note that forms[0] points on the first form on the page only, what if he has it under "login", "search" and "subscribe" form?

Comment: I will try this as well and see if it works same as that provided by vladkras below, Thanks!

Comment: @vladkras Why would you have to note something that I did already note?

Comment: @Trylks, sorry, I didn't notice it, but I can show you the better way